# Bootstrap 4 and IE11

Tags: magento2, head, meta

why my BT4 isn't working on IE11 ?

In default_head_block.xml I have this :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <css src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
    </body>
</page>
```

In my inspector, I have this (without the space between "<" and "meta"):

> < meta name="" content="IE-Edge"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="x_ua_compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

Comment: I tried yesterday, but bootstrap was still not working (I ran c:c, should I try something else ? )

Comment: did my solution help with metatag issue? Boostrap not working after metatags set correctly?

Comment: Not working, even if I think this is the solution (I tried this but not working...)